# Data truncation error while setting INOUT parameter in Stored Procedure

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc, db2, ibm-midrange

I'm calling a stored procedure which has INOUT parameters. Database is AS400 DB2. Type is CHARACTER. I'm getting Data Truncation error while registering and setting the variable. If I set the string directly to the column, it does not have an issue. If I set the same string in a variable and use it to set the column, it throws Data truncation error. Could you please let me know where I'm going wrong and how I can set the value of the column using a variable without causing exception? **Please see the end of error stack trace for more information.**

```
try{
     String cstmt_str = "CALL " + storedProcName + "(?)";
     String status="REJ"; 
     cstmt = conn.prepareCall(cstmt_str);
     cstmt.registerOutParameter("5506STS", Types.CHAR);
     //cstmt.setString("5506STS","REJ"); does not give a problem
     cstmt.setString("5506STS",status); //Data truncation Exception occurs here.
     cstmt.execute();
     }catch (DataTruncation de) {
          logger.error("DatatruncationException error:", de );
            displayError(de);
            de.printStackTrace();           
     }

public static void displayError(DataTruncation dataTruncation) {
    logger.info("Data truncation error: ");
    logger.info("dataTruncation.getDataSize():"+dataTruncation.getDataSize() + " number of bytes of data that should have been transferred.");
    if (!dataTruncation.getRead()) 
       logger.info("dataTruncation.getRead() is False. Its Written (Error:). ");
   logger.info("dataTruncation.getTransferSize():"+dataTruncation.getTransferSize()
    + " number of bytes of data actually transferred.");
  }

Stored Procedure Signature:
Number Mode   Name     DataType  Length
1      INOUT  5506STS  CHARACTER 3

I tried to find out the length of the string status:

int len = status.getBytes().length; // Output: 5
```

**I'm out of options. Please let me know how to successfully set the value in the variable "status" into "5506STS".**

**ERROR TRACE:**

```
DatatruncationException error:
java.sql.DataTruncation: Data truncation
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCPreparedStatement.testDataTruncation(AS400JDBCPreparedStatement.java:3450)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCPreparedStatement.setValue(AS400JDBCPreparedStatement.java:3361)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCPreparedStatement.setString(AS400JDBCPreparedStatement.java:2999)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCCallableStatement.setString(AS400JDBCCallableStatement.java:3082)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedCallableStatement.setString(WrappedCallableStatement.java:1563)
    at com.ssss.ssjtracdbws.dao.SSJTracDBWSDAO.submitNewRequestJSON(SSJTracDBWSDAO.java:699)
    at com.ssss.ssjtracdbws.webservices.SSJTracDBService.submitNewRequestJSON(SSJTracDBService.java:163)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:167)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:269)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:227)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:216)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:542)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:524)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:126)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcessor.java:353)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:911)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$ChannelProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:920)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 Data truncation error: 
 dataTruncation.getDataSize():5 number of bytes of data that should have been transferred.
 dataTruncation.getRead() is False. Its Written (Error:). 
 dataTruncation.getTransferSize(): 3 number of bytes of data actually transferred.
```

Comment: This is of course obvious, but since you didn't mention it, how did you make sure that the value of your variable did not exceed the SP parameter capacity? And what is the stored procedure signature?

Comment: 1 INOUT DS5506ETT CHARACTER 2
2 INOUT DS5506NWR CHARACTER 10
3 INOUT DS5506STS CHARACTER 3
is the definition of the SP. How I made sure is, I have String variables that makes sure it does not exceed the parameter length.Ex:
For DS5506ETT, String exceptionTimeType="JD"(just 2 letters)
For DS5506NWR, String nwReasonCode=" "(just 1 space which is < 10)
For DS5506STS, String newStatus="PND"(just 3 letters)
If I setString as "JD" directly, it does'nt throw error.IF I give variable name instead, it throws error.I printed variable name & made sure there R no addtnl spaces.@mustaccio

Comment: Might be related to character set conversion. What does `exceptionTimeType.getBytes("UTF-8").length` show?

Comment: @mustaccio it says 4. For Database type CHARACTER, the corresponding java type is String right? I couldnt figure out what else is it expecting.

Comment: Well, there you go. I'm not sure how the IBM Access driver does the character set conversion between Java and the server; looks like there is a [special Java API](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzahh/javadoc/com/ibm/as400/access/AS400Text.html) for that.

Comment: `CHARACTER(2)` expects two single-byte characters (2 bytes), while your Java string (in UTF-8) takes 4 bytes, hence truncation. You need to convert between the Java code page and the server code page.

Comment: @mustaccio, thank you for letting me know. I'll try it with the Java API you mentioned. But then, 1) how does cstmt.setString("DS5506ETT","JD") take just 2 bytes? 2) cstmt.registerOutParameter("DS5506ETT", Types.CHAR); remains the same right?

Comment: @mustaccio, I checked the Java API you mentioned about. I'm not able to know how to apply the API to my code. When I say As400Text. I can only see constants but no methods. Pardon me, could you please guide me in applying the API, so that cstmt.setString("DS5506ETT",exceptionTimeType); does not cause exception?

Comment: Please help.. anyone?

Comment: Hello @mustaccio , I think I missed one information when I gave the SP signature. 1 INOUT DS5506ETT CHARACTER(2) & CCSID=37. Would this be of any help? How could I make cstmt.registerOutParameter("DS5506ETT", Types.CHAR);
cstmt.setString("DS5506ETT",exceptionTimeType);//String exceptionTimeType="JD" work without exception? Could you please help me?

Comment: You may want to consider adding all the details from comments to the question itself -- it's really hard to follow all the bits and pieces.

Comment: @mustaccio I have added the information in the question. Hope it helps. Please let me know if any information is needed. This issue is still open :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found it out myself. The "status" that was passed to the function had a single quote surrounding it.('APP') this made the length 5 instead of 3. Now I removed the single quotes.Its working fine.